# Postgresql: find rows by ids

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

I want to get rows from database(postgresql) by ids, but I want to make sure I am doing it correctly.

I have some users in the table `users` and I want to get some of them by ids. Example:  `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=100 or id=250 LIMIT 2`

I want it to search for 100 and 250 and when `id=100` is found, it will only look for `id=250` but I am not 100% sure if internally the database is doing so

Is this possible and how can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want BOTH 100 & 250

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=100 or id=250 LIMIT 2;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN(100,250) LIMIT 2;
```

(they are equivalent queries)

It does not matter in what order they are discovered, 250 might be found first, but the query will only return one row for 100 if it exists and another row for  250 if it exists.

Comment: @everton IN() is merely a syntax shortcut for exactly the same predicates as the first query, so I doubt that assertion can be proven or be applicable to all situations.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I want both but note that those are ids so it is unnecessary to keep looking for that id if it is already found because they are unique. Is there no problem with it?

Comment: correct, there is no problem with that. If that ID column is a primary index (or any unique index) then the query will go direct to those rows

Comment: yes, id is primary key. I see, postgres already does it for me when it detects this field is a primary key and only looks  for this id once.

Answer (score -3):

SELECT *
FROM
table_name
WHERE
id = '07629486-9d0c-488c-a3ae-10e55a997752';

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to avoid duplicate answers.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please have a read at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer